# Conditionally add target="_blank" to links based on href, even when the href is interpolated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

There is a similar question out there, but it only applies to hard-coded hrefs, not ones that are interpolated by angular.  See [Conditionally add target="_blank" to links with Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584201/conditionally-add-target-blank-to-links-with-angular-js)

The solution I'm looking for is best illustrated by the following directive:

```
yourModule.directive('a', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var a = elem[0];
      if (location.host.indexOf(a.hostname) !== 0)
        a.target = '_blank';
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the directive runs before angular has done any interpolation, and therefore all links appear relative.  Is there a clean way to do this?  I can't use mutation observers, because I must support IE9.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use 2 option that was already provided:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="{{condition ? '_blank' : '_self'}}">Link</a>
```

and set condition variable in directive controller, depending on location.

If you provide sandbox for this issue it would be really helpful.

**UPD:** if you want to have more hacks you could you **$timeout** and wrap it there.

Comment: This would require adding markup to every link.  I am looking for a solution that wouldn't require additional markup.

Comment: I got your point. But it's normal to add attribute otherwise it would be attribute directive. ".directive('a'," - look's like hack for me

Comment: I disagree that .directive('a')... would be a hack.  It does exactly what I want it to do -- change the behavior of all links to open external hrefs in a new tab.  It's the opposite of a hack IMO.  It's elegant and totally self-contained.

Comment: I would say you extend element behaviour in non-declarative way. For me it's like extend/rewrite JS native object prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

The solution ended up being quite simple.  Angular provides a built-in way to observe attributes and react to changes:

```
yourModule.directive('a', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      attrs.observe('href', function(){
        var a = elem[0];
        if (location.host.indexOf(a.hostname) !== 0)
          a.target = '_blank';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope you know that you replace the built-in `a` directive and lose its functionality.